# Assigning position variable in bash

Tags: bash

How to assign a position variable in the if condition?

For example, my script name is `test.sh`. If I give the first variable as "T", I would like to see the printed variable $2 and $3.  The primary reason is to use the $2 and $3 variable in other cases later. 
I would like to set the variable $2 and $3 10, and 15 respectively.

```
 #!/bin/bash

echo "The first variable : $1"
echo "The second variable  : $2"
echo "The third variable : $3"
if [ $1 == "T" ]
        then
         $2 = 10
         $5 = 15
fi
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
```

The error shows: "command not found". I guess I'm making a syntax error?

Comment: The statetment `$2 = 10` is not even an assignment. It invokes the program stored in position variable `2`, and passes to it the parameters `= ` and `10`. If `$2` is empty (because you did not supply a second parameter), it tries to call a command named `=` with the parameter `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have a syntax error. The way to assign to a variable is `NAME=VALUE`. Note no dollar sign, and no spaces around the equals sign. However, `2=VALUE` is also not valid since a number is not a valid name. `$2` is actually a [parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters), not a variable.

You're not meant to assign to numbered parameters. You can do it using `set --`, but the better method is to give them names as variables, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

first="$1"
second="$2"
third="$3"

echo "The first variable: $first"
echo "The second variable: $second"
echo "The third variable: $third"
if [ "$first" == "T" ]; then
    second=10
    third=15
fi
echo "$second"
echo "$third"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign to "position variables" (parameters). You can however use set, but you might lose the other parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "The first variable : $1"
echo "The second variable  : $2"
echo "The third variable : $3"
if [ "$1" == "T" ]
        then
        set -- T 10 15
fi
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
```

If you want to keep the other parameters, you will need to use `"$@"` and `shift`:

```
$ set -- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ echo "$@"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ set -- T 10 15
$ echo "$@"
T 10 15
$ set -- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ shift 3
$ set -- T 10 15 "$@"
$ echo "$@"
T 10 15 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

if you are willing to forgo POSIX compatibility, you can also use [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) suggestion in bash/zsh:

```
$ set -- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ echo "${@:4}"
4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ set -- T 10 15 "${@:4}"
$ echo "$@"
T 10 15 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Note: "position variables" are actually [shell parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters). Also, you clearly stated that you want to use them, but I have to tell you that most of the time you are better using normal shell variables.

Comment: Bash supports the notation `"${@:4}"` to mean "all arguments from $4 onward", so rather than writing `shift 3` and then using `"$@"`, a somewhat simpler option is to write `set -- "$1" 10 15 "${@:4}"`.